# How can i convert String to Bitmap image on Java

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

There is a bitmap codes in the text file. I need to convert these codes as String to Bitmap and display them to the user on the screen. I wrote a code like below, but decodedByte is null. Where am I making a mistake?

```
try {
   BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("/data/user/0/com.example.lockertestapplication/files/text.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
   String line;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      data.append(line);
   }
   reader.close();
   String text = data.toString();
   byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);
   Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
   img.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
                
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I believe you are missing something here. decodeByteArray is used to turn a ByteArray of a Bitmap object back to Bitmap object. You can't just turn a String into byte[] and then to Bitmap, what do you expect to get? If you want a Bitmap that will hold the text of the file You'll want to maybe work with something like Canvas that you can then draw on and write text on

Comment: No. @Dan Baruch, decodeByteArray can decode a jpg file which is in that array. Not a bitmap object whatever that would look like.

Comment: I meant you can't read a String from a file and expect it to be converted to an image unless you wrote a byte[] of an image to the file and then you are reading it, but in which case you would read it with a bytebuffer rather than string buffer

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be related to the following:

1. String in your text file might not be correctly base64-encoded or corrupted.

2.In your code you are using Base64 Default for decoding instead of that try Base64.NO Wrap or other flags

3.It is also possible that the bitmap is too large for the memory, this is a possibility if you are uncourting OutOfMemoryError along with this error

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be in removing Base64 identifier from Base64 encoded text.
First, we need to split our Base64 string to get rid of the first part before “,”(comma)

```
String text = base64String.split(",")[1];
```

And then you are good to with your implemented method

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```